# Array of string in Process in java has space in a parameter

Tags: java, macos, perl, terminal

I write some java code in order to execute some external commands in the mac terminal.
The original command to run in the terminal is

```
xpl-sender -c plugwise.basic -m xpl-cmnd command=livepower device=B83229 -w 3
```

It is really weird because if I use the command string array likes this:

```
Process ls = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
   "/usr/local/bin/xpl-sender",
   "-c", "plugwise.basic",
   "-m", "xpl-cmnd",
   "command=" + command,
   "device=" + id});
```

Without "-w 3", thing works normally but of course it lacks of parameters.

But if i use like this

```
Process ls = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
   "/usr/local/bin/xpl-sender",
   "-c", "plugwise.basic",
   "-m", "xpl-cmnd",
   "command=" + command,
   "device=" + id,
   "-w 3"});
```

With "-w 3" at the end, nothing works anymore, the command seems that it isn't executed.

And if I use like this

```
Process ls = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
   "/usr/local/bin/xpl-sender",
   "-c", "plugwise.basic",
   "-m", "xpl-cmnd",
   "command=" + command,
   "device=" + id + " -w 3"});
```

With +" -w 3"at the end, the perl program which is used to executed the command will return

```
Illegal hexadecimal digit '-' ignored at /Library/Perl/5.12/xPL/Dock/Plugwise.pm line 964.
```

It seems that the error caused by the space between -w and 3....

Can someone show me what i did wrong here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to split the string up - "w" and "3", not "-w 3".

Comment: oh thank you very much, u should answer it so I can mark as accepted

Comment: np, and good luck with the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way the Runtime interprets arguments, you need to split the string up: `"-w"` and `"3"`, not `"-w 3"`. The designers chose to implement this behavior because there *are* some cases where you want to specify arguments with spaces in them. E.g:

> grep -r -e "Where are they now" .

Rather than making developers have to manually escape the string "Where are they now", in the example above, the Runtime allows for one to simply pass the entire string as an argument, which then gets passed to the underlying process.  It does mean however that in cases like this:

> ls -al ~

That each argument needs to be passed to the Runtime separately. In the above example if you passed in one argument as "ls -al", it would actually be passed to the underlying process as ***one*** string, and of course, the process would fail because there is no existing binary with that name.

Comment: Your reason is all wrong. Requiring `-w 3` as two arguments has nothing to do with allowing spaces, since spaces are valid values for `-w` operand. The real reason is simply: It's easier to parse if you only accept one syntax instead of two (`'-w 3'` and `-w 3`), and makes for more consistent calls.

Comment: @ikegami - sorry, I can't follow your reasoning at all. You said 'operand', which is the keyword. Any component of your command that is semantically separate needs to be passed in as a separate string.

Comment: "`-w`'s operand' is what I called `3`. Seemed better than "argument `-w`'s argument".

Comment: Furthermore, your new reasoning that semantically separate arguments need be passed as separate strings is also wrong.  `perl` accepts `perl '-n -i'`, for example.

Comment: @ikegami - obviously, different programs process command line arguments in different ways. What is 'semantically separate' for one program very well may not be for another.

Comment: I never said otherwise. I simply contradicted the blatantly wrong claim that "any component of your command that is semantically separate needs to be passed in as a separate string."

Comment: @ikegami - we are going to have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the equivalent of shell command

```
xpl-sender ... '-w 3'   # One 4-char arg
```

instead of

```
xpl-sender ... -w 3     # Two args
```

You want:

```
Process ls = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
   "/usr/local/bin/xpl-sender",
   "-c", "plugwise.basic",
   "-m", "xpl-cmnd",
   "command=" + command,
   "device=" + id,
   "-w", "3"});
```

Since most programs don't accept options after non-options (although you report it works for your `xml-sender`), and because it looks better, I'd move the `-w` up.

```
Process ls = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
   "/usr/local/bin/xpl-sender",
   "-c", "plugwise.basic",
   "-m", "xpl-cmnd",
   "-w", "3",
   "command=" + command,
   "device=" + id});
```